# Represent number as a bytes using 16-bit blocks

Tags: python, python-3.x

I wish to convert a number like `683550` (0xA6E1E) to `b'\x1e\x6e\x0a\x00'`, where the number of bytes in the array is a multiple of 2 and where the len of the bytes object is only so long as it needs to be to represent the number.

This is as far as I got:

```
"{0:0{1}x}".format(683550,8)
```

giving:

```
'000a6e1e'
```

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/library/struct.html#format-strings

Comment: What's up with the crazy byte order? That's not big-endian or little-endian.

Comment: @user2357112 I'm sorry. The reason it was messed up was because I was using "hexdump -x" to view the bytes in the file. Without the -x it makes more sense.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `.tobytes`-method:

```
num = 683550
bytes = num.to_bytes((num.bit_length()+15)//16*2, "little")
```

Comment: Outputting [hex(i) for i in t] for your answer gives ['0x1e', '0x6e', '0xa', '0x0']. I'm looking for  ['0x6e', '0x1e', '0x0','0xa']

Comment: so you really want this mixed little-big-endian stuff. So see my updated answer.

Comment: I'm sorry @Daniel, your original answer was indeed correct. I was using "hexdump -x" to view the file which was switching things around. I've edited my question with the correct bytes.

Comment: so back again, again.

Answer (score 0):

Using python3:

```py
def encode_to_my_hex_format(num, bytes_group_len=2, byteorder='little'):
  """
  @param byteorder can take the values 'little' or 'big'
  """
  bytes_needed = abs(-len(bin(num)[2: ]) // 8)

  if bytes_needed % bytes_group_len:
    bytes_needed += bytes_group_len - bytes_needed % bytes_group_len

  num_in_bytes = num.to_bytes(bytes_needed, byteorder)
  encoded_num_in_bytes = b''

  for index in range(0, len(num_in_bytes), bytes_group_len):
    bytes_group = num_in_bytes[index: index + bytes_group_len]

    if byteorder == 'little':
      bytes_group = bytes_group[-1: -len(bytes_group) -1 : -1]

    encoded_num_in_bytes += bytes_group

  encoded_num = ''

  for byte in encoded_num_in_bytes:
    encoded_num += r'\x' + hex(byte)[2: ].zfill(2)

  return encoded_num

print(encode_to_my_hex_format(683550))
```

Comment: You need to output bytes not a string.

Comment: Then just return encoded_num_in_bytes instead of encoded_num in the function.